# Magento 1.9 Hide Taxes in Checkout and Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, taxes

How can I hide taxes in Checkout and cart?
The taxes should be still calculated in total, but not shown to the customer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Admin > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings**

Change `Display Full Tax Summary` to **NO**

Comment: still nothing, the tax is still there

Comment: hymmm is there a chance that the theme is displaying the tax? Are there any settings for the theme in regards to this? Also try truing on template paths and find a phtml file that renders the prices and remove it from there :)

Comment: I found the phtml file, and this is how is displayed <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>, and this is the function 
  
    public function renderTotals($area = null, $colspan = 1)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach($this->getTotals() as $total) {
            if ($total->getArea() != $area && $area != -1) {
                continue;
            }
            $html .= $this->renderTotal($total, $area, $colspan);
        }
        return $html;
    } I dont know how to hide only the tax (this function also generates the the shiping cost and subtotal rows, which I want to keep

Comment: Hymmm how about using css or jquery to hide this element?

Answer (score 3):

In my knowledge you can hide this from **Admin Panel**, you need to go into 
**system -> configurations -> tax**. Here you will find display settings from where you can hide it.

Comment: you are correct ;) we answered almost the same time :) Upvote from me :D

Comment: The tax is still there..